# How to ignore <BR> tag while printing in console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print a table having one column heading as - `Assigned <BR> On`. When I am printing this table heading in console, due to this BR tag, entire table is not getting printed in desired structure. Till it reaches Assigned, printed in one line, then from On it goes down to another line. So structure of the table is not in correct format. I am using Selenium WebDriver and my goal is to print this table with the same structure it is displaying in the web page. Not finding a way how to ignore this `<BR>` tag.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: System.out.print(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='viewHlpTkt']/thead/tr[2]/th["+i+"]")).getText().replace("br", " "));

Comment: I tried with .replace("<BR>", " ") as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check String regex replacement may help:

```
String testString = "abc/d <BR> ff</BR>";
testString = testString.replaceAll("<BR>|</BR>", "");
```

Comment: Html code : Last Assigned<br>On
My selenium code to print table : System.out.print(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='viewHlpTkt']/thead/tr[2]/th["+i+"]")).getText().replaceAll("<br>", ""));   As you have suggested I changed to replaceAll(). Still not working.